# Vue Reading in parallel in a loop

Tags: vue.js

I have an Set array which contains multiple Ids.I would like to loop through the Set and make the api calls in parallel for each id and get back the user object, add it to a map.How can i achieve it.

The value is Set
userIds :Set[2]
0:"1"
1:"2"

```
 data() {
   return {
    userIds: new Set(), 
  };
},

 const res = getUsers(userId)
```

Comment: write declarative code instead of messy code. as you are thinking code will be messy. since javascript is asynchronous so it is achievable.

Comment: you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438119/vue-best-practices-for-handling-multiple-api-calls

Comment: I would like to call same api in parallel with multiple ids.The above answer you referred  is different.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will resolve your issues. i did not test, just writing code here directly.

```
    // set requests
    let allRequests = []
    //you can use other loop based on your decession
    this.userIds.forEach(id => { allRequests.push(axios.get(`your_url\${id}`)) })
    
    // you can use await it is based on you requirement
    axios.all(allRequests).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
      //make your map here using responses
    })).catch(errors => {
      // react on errors.
    })
```

you can check this [reference](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/using+axios+to+fetch+multiple+urls)